# EXTJS modern combobox autocomplete spinner picker instead of usual picker

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs6-modern

We do have a combobox to autocomplete like a search field.

If it is on the modern toolkit. the picker is changed to the spinner selector and you cannot type anymore.

How can I prevent the picker change in modern or how could I do like a search autocomplete in the modern framework.

seems like if you set the combobox queryMode to remote, it does not work well in the modern framework.

```
{
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        itemId: 'cmbName',
                        style: { color: '#4944FF' },
                        viewModel: {
                            type: 'peopleModel'
                        },
                        bind: {
                            store: '{peopleStore}'
                        },
                        hideLabel: true,
                        enableKeyEvents: true,
                        placeholder: 'Enter name (type min. 3 letters)',
                        hiddenName: 'lastname',
                        name: 'lastname',
                        forceSelection: false,
                        submitValue: false,
                        displayField: 'lastname',
                        valueField: 'lastname',
                        queryMode: 'remote',
                        matchFieldWidth: false,
                        multiSelect: false,
                        minChars: 3,
                        pageSize: 10,
                        listeners: {
                            select: 'onSelect'
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I copied this code to a Fiddle and I was able to type into the combo. `queryMode` should be `remote` if you filter the records on the server side.

Comment: If you do it in mobile mode, it will change to a spinner picker and not like a normal dropbox. Is this triggered by something else?

Comment: What do you mean by `mobile mode`?

Comment: When you for example in chrome go to More Tools -> Developer Tools. At the top left corner you can switch it to a device. If you then select iphone for example and reload the page, you are getting this spinner selector

Comment: Do you experience this in [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3i7o)? I can still enter text in mobile mode, both queryMode local and remote.